# is there a way to extract the value from a Django dictionary by the key index value

Tags: django, dictionary

I'm parsing a dictionary in Django from the request. 
I know I can extract the value using the key name like so: `myDict=request_data['myDict']`
now i would like to do this `obj1= myDict[0]` instead of `obj1= myDict['obj1']`

but it doesn't seems to work, ant suggestions?

Comment: How should it tell the difference between your `0` and an actual `0`?

Comment: obj1 = myDict.values[0]  maybe?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not sure I follow you, but myDict is a dictionary by itself already extracted from the request, so it has 0..n keys that is why i can iterate over it with a for loop

Comment: @smarber tried that got this error `obj1=myDict.values[0]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different from a list a dictionary has 'keys'. I'm guessing you are referring to the iterating over the different keys that your dictionary has.

what you want to do is something like this:

```
keys = myDict.keys()
obj1 = myDict[keys[0]]
```